# how to mock a servletContext instead of Servlet or HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mockito

I have an independent project for writing test cases; the problem is I can't mock `HttpServletRequest`, simply because in my servlet there are calls like `getServletContext()` as test cases are running from the outside servlet container. It will always return an error saying "no context found". This is just one dependency with the servlet container; there can be hundreds. For example, `initialContext.lookup()` also depends on a container.

How can I use Mockito to write a test case in this scenario? Please don't ask for an error message; it's more of a logical problem than technical.

Looking on the internet for tutorials makes me wonder if I am doing something seriously wrong. No one seems to have encountered this problem before... How can you mock `HttpServletRequest` without ever having `getServletContext()` called in the servlet? I mean seriously, how rare can it be?

Comment: even if you can point me in right direction it would be enough.

Comment: If you are using spring they all ready have a class MockHttpServletRequest http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a servlet implementation that uses the `ServletContext`, e.g.

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        Object attribute = servletContext.getAttribute("test");
        System.out.println(attribute.toString());
   }
}
```

in this case you have 2 options to test the `doGet` method

Use powermock's [partitial mocking](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial) to only mock the `getServletContext` method.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SomeServletTest {

    @Test
    public void onGet() throws ServletException, IOException{
        SomeServlet someServlet = PowerMock.createPartialMock(SomeServlet.class, "getServletContext");   
        ServletContext servletContext = PowerMock.createNiceMock(ServletContext.class);
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PowerMock.createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = PowerMock.createNiceMock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        someServlet.getServletContext();
        PowerMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(servletContext);

        servletContext.getAttribute("test");
        PowerMock.expectLastCall().andReturn("hello");

        PowerMock.replay(someServlet, servletContext, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        someServlet.doGet(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

or a simpler way is to just override the `getServletContext` method. In this case you don't need powermock. You can just do it using easymock. e.g.

```
public class SomeServletTest {

    @Test
    public void onGet() throws ServletException, IOException{
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = EasyMock.createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = EasyMock.createNiceMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        final ServletContext servletContext = EasyMock.createNiceMock(ServletContext.class);
        SomeServlet someServlet = new SomeServlet(){
            public ServletContext getServletContext() {
                return servletContext; // return the mock
            }
        };

        EasyMock.expect(servletContext.getAttribute("test")).andReturn("hello");
        EasyMock.replay(servletContext, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        someServlet.doGet(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

> there can be 100's. like initialContext.lookup() also dependent on container.

In this case you can either create an `InitialContext` mock and use this.
If your code creates a new `InitialContext`, e.g.

```
public void someMethod(){
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    context.lookup(....);
}
```

you can simply extract the `InitialContext` instantiation to a protected method that you can override in your tests like I showed above with the `ServletContext`

```
public void someMethod(){
    InitialContext context = createInitialContext();
    context.lookup(....);
}

protected InitialContext createInitialContext(){
    return new InitialContext(); // can be overridden by a subclass 
                                 // and therefore by tests as well to
                                 // return a mock
}
```

If you don't want or you can't modify the code in this way, then you can use `Powermock` to [intercept the constructor](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

**EDIT**

> Can you post your Mockito code? It would be a pleasure, since the methods are named differently.

```
@Test
public void onGet() throws ServletException, IOException {
  HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
  HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
  final ServletContext servletContext = Mockito.mock(ServletContext.class);
  SomeServlet someServlet = new SomeServlet(){
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
      return servletContext; // return the mock
    }
  };

  Mockito.doReturn("hello").when(servletContext).getAttribute("test");

  someServlet.doGet(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

Comment: Sorry wrote my answer to use EasyMock. But the same applies for Mockito.

Comment: wonderful , looks good , i give it a try tomorrow , thank you soo much

Comment: Can you post your Mockito code? It would be a pleasure, since the methods are named differently.

Comment: Upvote for mockito. I love complete answers like these. I also had noidea you could add methods to objects when instantiating them.